# Black edge in round-corner thumbnail images (Emporio theme)?

Tags: css

After I use this code for rounded-corners thumbnail (emporio theme), there are black edges, how can i remove them ? Thanks in advance!

```
.snippet-thumbnail {
-moz-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-khtml-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;;
border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

[black edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYkaK.png)

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. It's better if you provide a complete code.

Comment: And, just in case, also a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: You have to show us also the html! We can guess only you rounded corner with your code. I'll suggest to read [mcve] and then update your question accordingly

Comment: Anw, thanks Kilian for the helpful cssmatic!

Comment: If you find a solution, please post it , so if someone has the same issue he can solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[cssmatic](https://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius)
to edit your border. There you can adjust everything and create it, as you want it to. You simply have to replace the code in css then.

Like so:

```
.snippet-thumbnail {
border-radius: 11px 17px 17px 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 11px 17px 17px 17px;
-webkit-border-radius: 11px 17px 17px 17px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
}
```

That´s how you can adjust and make your own custom borders.

Comment: thanks but  there still black edges on thumbnail :( i use emporio theme.

Comment: its okay, i found solution, thank you for that cssmatic anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code I used

```
.snippet-thumbnail {
-moz-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-khtml-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;;
border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

It does not affect the container which include the image, thats why there are black edges. So you need to add

```
snippet-thumbnail-container {
padding: 0 !important;
background: none !important;  border: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
-khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```